# Make bootstrap popover appear over a different element than its trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popup

I'm trying to have a single "NEXT" button create different popovers (popover 1, 2, 3 etc...): Each popover should appear attached to a different div on the page.

We are trying to create a "Take a Tour" functionality where different features are explained by different popovers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Show/hide your popovers manually.

On the click of your 'Next' button, show and hide your popovers in sequence:

```
var currentPopover = -1;
var popovers = [];

// Initialize all the popovers to be "manually" displayed.
popovers.push($("#ctrl1").popover({ trigger: 'manual' }));
popovers.push($("#ctrl2").popover({ trigger: 'manual' }));
popovers.push($("#ctrl3").popover({ trigger: 'manual' }));

// On each button click, hide the currently displayed popover
// and show the next one.
$("#NextBtn").click(function() {
  if (currentPopover >= 0) {
    popovers[currentPopover].popover('hide');
  }

  currentPopover = currentPopover + 1;
  popovers[currentPopover].popover('show');
});
```

*The above code has not been compiled or tested.*

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. However how can I program it such that:popover #1 displays over div #1, popover #2 over div#2 etc...

Comment: Create them as popovers on those controls exactly as you normally would (just with the manual trigger).  See my example code.